# Google maps Directions API - URL can be parameterized via POST?

Tags: http, google-maps, post, get

I would like to **ask to confirm** if the Google maps URL:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json

Can be parameterized via POST. I tried use it via GET **in explorer**, like that:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.90119000000001,-87.62979000000001&destination=34.052360,-118.243560&sensor=false&units=metric&language=en-US

And works fine, but if I try to use it via POST **in my Android app**, sending this query through OutputStream:

> origin=19.369707,-99.266696&destination=19.022489,-98.615814&sensor=false&units=metric&language=es

I get this error:

> {   "routes" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests trying to retrieve the JSON object from:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json
```

I can assume that only is possible to parameterize it via GET.

You cannot parameterize the Google Maps Directions URL via POST.

I hope it helps someone.